# Filter record through dates not working laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have a expiry_date (type=date) column in my table

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
$Data = Post::whereDate('expiry_date','<=',$currentDate)->where(['status' => 'active'])->orWhere(['p_id' => 3])->select('id','title','status','p_id','expiry_date')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

i want to filter data if current date is greater than expiry date then those record should not be shown but in my scenario i'm still getting record.

Any solution Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must group `orWhere` clause in closure. Grouping in closure is like `()` in real query.

```
$Data = Post::whereDate('expiry_date','<=',$currentDate)
    ->where(function($query){
        return $query
            ->where(['status' => 'active'])
            ->orWhere(['p_id' => 3]);
    })
    ->select('id','title','status','p_id','expiry_date')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

But, because I don't know your project - i may wrong with grouping.